# How to get the structure of Msg Table of Edb files?

Tags: exchange-server, esent, edb

I am trying to read the offline edb files.What i have now is the tables of edb files i want to know the structure of the tables.Any help

Comment: Be spesific. I thinki you should paste some code here..

Answer (score 1):

You should read the MSysObjects table of your edb database. In there you will find all tables and their respective columns listed. Ideally you should dump the table comma or tab separated. Then you can comfortably look for all tables or columns within Excel.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the documentation created by Joachim Metz. He analyzed almost all tables of the Exchange database.

Here's the link to his project: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/libesedb/files/